# Class cast exception in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, classcastexception

I want to upload an image using a groovy on grails.
My gsp page is as follows (I am showing a simplified version of the original)

```
<g:form controller="post" action="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
      My picture  <input type="file" name="myPicture" />     
    <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Save"/>
</g:form>
```

My domain class is as follows:

```
class Post {    

byte[] myPicture

static mapping = {
    myPicture type:  "blob" 
}
```

I need this mapping otherwise MySql will create a smallblob which is to small to fit the images

```
static constraints = {
    myPicture(nullable:false)      
}

}
```

At the controller I have an action called save which is as follows:

```
def save = {                               
    def post = loadPost(params.id)

    post.properties = params

    if(post.save()) {
        print "hallo world"             
        redirect(action:'list', params:params)
    } else {
        render(view:'edit', model:[post:post])
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when I try to save the image at the DB.

```
2009-04-27 18:16:07,319 [20806951@qtp0-0] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

Any hint why is this?

BTW, I've seen in a tutorial that images were handled as strings but it didn't work
as well.

Comment: What does your loadPost() method do?

Comment: Nothing special
private loadPost(id) {
        def post = new Post();
        if(id) {
            post = Post.get(id)
        }
        return post
    }

Comment: @Miguel Ping has provided a piece of code which is correct for the upload but doesn't solve the Class Cast Exception. for "saving" the image the method getBytes() must be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way:

```
  def save = {                               

    def post = loadPost(params.id)

    def f = request.getFile('myPicture')             

    post.myPicture = f.getBytes()
    post.pictureType = f.getContentType()                    


    if(post.save()) {
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar question on Nabble:

http://www.nabble.com/MySQL-and-Blobs-td16116885.html

Two possible solutions are suggested:

- Change the constraints of the blob property to a large max-size, to stop it from using "TinyBlob".
- Use the Hibernate Blob implementation instead of byte[] for the property's type declaration.  This will require you stream data into the Blob, instead of direct assignment, but the post above gives code to do so.

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution for the class cast exception

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using Spring's [MultipartFile](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) within your `loadPost()` method?

Here's an example from the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/1.1/guide/single.html#6.1.8%20Uploading%20Files):

```
def upload = {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if(!f.empty) {
      f.transferTo( new File('/some/local/dir/myfile.txt') )
      response.sendError(200,'Done');
    }    
    else {
       flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
       render(view:'uploadForm')
    }
}
```

I believe you can access `f.bytes` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. getBytes() should be used. anyway this doesn't solve the ClassCastException. For solving this problem see @Bill James answer

Comment: As a side note, I think f.bytes is equivalente to f.getBytes(), since groovy dispatch the property access to the getter.

Comment: Thanks again. I will test it. I thought I've tried but I got an exception. Let's see.