# store large html text in database

Tags: mysql, grails, blob

In my Grails (2.2.1) project I would like to store some large html into a db field.
I've created the following domain class:

```
class SurgeryModule {

    byte[] html;

    static belongsTo = [doctor:Doctor]

    static constraints = {

        html sqlType: 'blob'
    }
}
```

but it creates a tinyblob field in mySql database. I've also tried with clob instead of blob.
How can I have a BLOB to store large data inside the DB?

Comment: I'd question storing markup in a database.  Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Why duffymo? if you need to have a simple editor for a pdf file, how do you store models for the pdfs?

Comment: vhu, with longblob I have the same result, that is a tinyblob as db field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a constraint

```
static mapping = {
    html (type:’longblob’)
}
```

Below it shows the different types of Blob data types supported in Mysql and its size

`TINYBLOB`: maximum length of 255 bytes

`BLOB`: maximum length of 65,535 bytes

`MEDIUMBLOB`: maximum length of 16,777,215 bytes

`LONGBLOB`: maximum length of 4,294,967,295 bytes

Comment: woops realize that `type` is the default for grails 3.x but `sqlType` is the property for grails 2.x - which version of grails are you running ? did you try to extend the maximum size ?

Comment: it works, but  I have the following exception when I store the value:[B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

Comment: did you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794357/class-cast-exception-in-groovy)

Comment: what part of the answer do I need to use?

Comment: the latest answer (validated as working) Two possible solutions are suggested:

Change the constraints of the blob property to a large max-size, to stop it from using "TinyBlob".
Use the Hibernate Blob implementation instead of byte[] for the property's type declaration. This will require you stream data into the Blob, instead of direct assignment, but the post above gives code to do so.

Comment: that post linked there is no more reachable :(

Comment: I've seen now your comment about sqlType. Using it with longblob works correctly,  without any exception. thanks!